# Move file from one folder to another folder in jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am downloading one file from repository and it gets downloaded in a particular folder for eg ${WORKSPACE}/test1/filename. I want to move this file to a new location like ${WORKSPACE}/filename.
I tried the following in my jenkins pipeline:
bat 'xcopy ${WORKSPACE}/test1 ${WORKSPACE}' but this did not work

Answer (score 0):

Why did it fail? Try to look at the output given by jenkins.

But I would recommend you use double quotation, since this allows for string interpolation, so your command should instead be:

```
bat "xcopy ${WORKSPACE}/test1 ${WORKSPACE}"
```

Of course this would only work if your Jenkins pipeline runs on a Windows node, for a UNIX-like node, you should instead use:

```
sh "mv ${WORKSPACE]/test1 ${WORKSPACE}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, apologies i pasted the bat command, it's linux actually. Also the output that jenkins gives is
mv: ‘<Workspace path>/test1’ and ‘<Workspace path>/test1’ are the same file

Answer (score 0):

sh "mv ${WORKSPACE]/test1/filename ${WORKSPACE}". Needed to add filename also to the path.